# Is it possible to whitelist IP addresses that can hit google cloud function URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I am looking for a way using which i can restrict the public URL endpoint for google cloud function

Basically we want to make sure that the endpoints we expose should only be invoke by specific thirdparty servers (List of ip address ranges). What authorization mechanism we can put at our endpoint to filter any request that is not originated from thirdparty server.

We do have list of ip address range for that third party service providers

Answer (score 3):

You can configure your function's [ingress settings](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#ingress_settings) to only allow internal traffic and traffic originating from a [Google Cloud Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs) (`ALLOW_INTERNAL_AND_GCLB` in [the API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#ingresssettings)), and then use [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview#ip-address-rules) in that Load Balancer.